# MongoDB lookup match two elements in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoid

I have a users collection who's document looks like this:

```
{
      "name": "James",
      "participations": [
        {
          participant_id: 1,
          participant_type: "Board",
          // other fields
        },
        {
          participant_id: 2,
          participant_type: "Team"
          // other fields
        }
      ]
    },
```

I am aggregating a users collection:

```
db.boards.aggregate([
  { '$match' => { _id: 65 } },
  { '$lookup' => 
        { from: "users", as: "users",
          let: { "board_id": "$_id" },
          pipeline: [
            { '$match' =>
               { '$expr' => {
                 '$and' => [
                    { '$in' => ["Board", "$participations.participant_type"] },
                    { '$in' => ["$$board_id", "$participations.participant_id"] }, 
                 ]
              }}
            }
          ],
        } 
      },
])
```

However, the above logic is flawed. If a user has a participation in a team with the id 65, then that user will show up, even though he doesn't have a participation in the board.

I want to select all the users who have a participation that has a participant_type of "Board" and a participant_id of 65. I tried using elemMatch, but apparently the aggregation framework doesn't support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not interested in every element in the participations array, you can accomplish your goal by `$unwind`ing the participations field. This will give you one document for each element in the array, which you can then match against like so:

```
pipeline: [
            { '$unwind' => '$participations' },
            { '$match' =>
               { '$expr' => {
                 '$and' => [
                    { '$eq' => ["Board", "$participations.participant_type"] },
                    { '$eq' => ["$$board_id", "$participations.participant_id"] }, 
                 ]
              }}
            }
          ]
```